# How to create a new Team inside team project using Rest API in TFS 2015

Tags: api, rest, tfs, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015 with Update 2. I am trying to use TFS rest APIs to create, update and delete contents in TFS instead of using the web interface.
We have out of the box API from TFS to create a Team project. But there are no APIs listed in [TFS Official](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/tfs/teams) to create a new Team inside Team project.

I tried Powertools exe. It too doesn't have a method to create new Team.

Could someone please help me with how to create a new Team inside team project using Rest API.

Comment: What's the detail mean of "Team inside team project"? What's the difference between the team inside team project with normal team project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest API can only get the teams in Team Project for now, it does not support create teams. Refer to this link for details: [Teams](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/tfs/teams). You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

The alternative way to achieve this is using [.NET client libraries for Visual Studio Team Services (and TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet), following is the code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

namespace ConsoleApplica
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string URL = "https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(URL));
            TfsTeamService tts = ttpc.GetService<TfsTeamService>();
            string teamprojecturi = "teamprojecturi";
            string newteamname = "newteam";
            string teamdescription = "newteamdescription";
            IDictionary<string, object> prop = null;//properties, can be null or empty
            tts.CreateTeam(teamprojecturi, newteamname,teamdescription,prop);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eddie. This helped. If you know then can you please help me on how tts.UpdateTeam() could be used to update area, Iteration, security on area and all other parameters inside a Team. I see everything inside as GUIDs only in the Team object.

Comment: UpdateTeam() method can only update the basic information of the team like Name, Description. You need to use the API for area, iteration, security related to achieve the feature you want. You can refer to this link for details: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/tag/tfs-api/